# Trouble taking two user chosen inputs and doing calculation

Tags: javascript, html, forms

My html code to take two user chosen input numbers and do calculation. Trouble having it actually do calculation after user chooses inputs. When I put in the two numbers and push calculate it doesnt do anything.

```
function calc(form)
{
if(isNaN(form.resistance.value))
 {
 alert("Error in input");
 return false;
 }

if(form.resistance.value.length > 32)
 {
 alert("Error in input");
 return false;
  }
 function calc(form1)
{
  if(isNaN(form1.strain.value))
 {
 alert("Error in input");
 return false;
}

 if(form1.strain.value.length > 32)
{
 alert("Error in input");
   return false;
} 



var Rchange = 2 * form1.strain.value * form.resistance.value;


 var newResistance =(parseInt(form.resistance.value) + Rchange);
document.getElementById("newResistance").innerHTML = chopTo4(newResistance);

}

function chopTo4(raw)
{
 strRaw = raw.toString();
 if(strRaw.length - strRaw.indexOf("0") > 4)
strRaw = strRaw.substring(0,strRaw.indexOf("0") + 5);
  return strRaw;
 }

</script>

</head>
<body>


<table>
<tr><form1><td>Enter Strain: </td><td><input style="text-align:right" type="text" name="strain"></td></tr>
</table>
<table>
<tr><form><td>Enter Resistance: </td><td><input style="text-align:right" type="text" name="resistance"></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan=2 align="center"><input type="button" value="Calculate" onClick="calc(this.form)"></td></form></tr>
<tr><td>New Resistance: </td><td id="newResistance"></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: notice: you can't put `<form>` between `<tr>` and `<td>` elements

Comment: and there are 2 closing table tags while only one opening table tag

Comment: and one more thing, I've tried to edit your code to improve formatting and I've noticed that there are many missing curly braces, if this is your actual code and not the result of copy-pasting then just fix your syntax errors, try your program if it still doesn't work come back with the code without syntax errors

Comment: Exactly, validate your js and html code first. For god sake use JsLint if you write so messy code! :P

Comment: Sorry I'm writing my code using Notepad++ so I don't see errors I'm just running my code straight to Web browser. I organized code a bit.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I figured it out on my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function calc(form)
{
 if(isNaN(form.resistance.value))
{
 alert("Error in input");
 return false;
 }

if(form.resistance.value.length > 32)
 {
 alert("Error in input");
 return false;
 }



var Rchange = 2 * form.strain.value * form.resistance.value;


var newResistance =(parseInt(form.resistance.value) + Rchange);
  document.getElementById("newResistance").innerHTML = chopTo4(newResistance);

  }

function chopTo4(raw)
{
 strRaw = raw.toString();
 if(strRaw.length - strRaw.indexOf("0") > 4)
strRaw = strRaw.substring(0,strRaw.indexOf("0") + 5);
return strRaw;
}

</script>

</head>
<body>


<table>
 <tr><form><td>Enter Strain: </td><td><input style="text-align:right" type="text" name="strain"></td></tr>
</table>
<table>
 <tr><form><td>Enter Resistance: </td><td><input style="text-align:right" type="text" name="resistance"></td></tr>
 <tr><td colspan=2 align="center"><input type="button" value="Calculate" onClick="calc(this.form)"></td></form></tr>
<tr><td>New Resistance: </td><td id="newResistance"></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This doesn't really class as an _answer_. Tell us what was wrong, and how you fixed it.

Comment: In my original code, the form for strain value I was inputting it and then calling a function to do a calculation  but I didn't want to that I just wanted to use the input value as like a variable.